# Mysql case insensitive search with match()

Tags: mysql

So here is the query...currently it is case sensitive, any idea how I can make it case insensitive?  I would just do a lower() in any other query but can I do that around the match()?

```
SELECT *,
MATCH(`page_titleTag`,`page_titleBody`,`page_url`,`page_desc`,`page_desc2`,`page_quickinfo`,`page_text`,`page_keywords`,`mtag_desc`) AGAINST('Search String') AS score
FROM page_tbl
WHERE
MATCH(`page_titleTag`,`page_titleBody`,`page_url`,`page_desc`,`page_desc2`,`page_quickinfo`,`page_text`,`page_keywords`,`mtag_desc`) AGAINST('Search String') AND `page_issearchable` = 1 AND `page_active` = 1
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 0, 15;
```

Comment: fulltext matches are case-insensitive by default, unless your collation is set to be case sensitive.

Comment: You could do lower() around each term in match(), if your collation is _CS

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm trying to think back to when I built this.  I see that the fields are set to utf8_bin but the collation can't be changed to anything else b/c of the fulltext (phpmyadmin gave me an error when I tried to change it)

Are you talking about the collation of the fields or the index or something else?  a little confused

Answer (score 0):

Text matching in SQL is always case-insensitive. [Here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/723-sql-server-text-matching-is-case-insensitive.htm) is a link which provides more info.