# Challenges with MySQL Fulltext Index, Case-Insensitive Search Yielding Unexpected Outcomes

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm facing an issue with a MySQL fulltext index when trying to perform a case-insensitive search. I have a large column in my database where data is stored, and I want to be able to search for text regardless of case. For instance, if my data contains the text "be biopharma," I expect the search for "Be" to return this row, but it's not working as intended.

I attempted to perform a case-insensitive search using a fulltext index in MySQL. I used the following SQL query:

`SELECT * FROM product WHERE MATCH(product.name) AGAINST ("+be*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

I expected this query to return rows that contain the text "be biopharma" when I search for "Be." However, the query did not return the expected results. This issue arises because MySQL's fulltext search, by default, is case-sensitive. I'm seeking guidance on how to modify the query or configure the fulltext index to correctly perform a case-insensitive search.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552053/mysql-case-insensitive-search-with-match#comment43530280_27552053: _"fulltext matches are case-insensitive by default, unless your collation is set to be case sensitive"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search for 2-character words using full-text check this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html). you have to do configuration based on the storage engine you use.

Along with that your search **"Be"** is a stopword check this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

- Create your own Stopword Table [InnoDb Only] as mentioned in the
  documentation
- Then You have to rebuild your index.